# Customer Reservations - <nameprefix>, does it exist in the Amadas API?

Tags: amadeus

I troubleshooting an issue downstream of the GDS and I wanted to confirm if Amadas has an <namePrefix> XML object for customer reservation.

When that data is being ingested into its destination, this is what I would like to be seeing:

```
<IndividualName>
<namePrefix>Mr</namePrefix>
<nameFirst>FIRST</nameFirst>
<nameSur>SUR</nameSur>
```

But I'm seeing

```
<IndividualName>
          <nameFirst>JOHN MR</nameFirst>
          <nameSur>DOE</nameSur>
</IndividualName>
```

If they do, then I'll engage with the party between the GDS and our PMS to resolve the issue but I need to be sure if this XML object exists.

Regards

At this stage, I've traced the missing XML Object back to the stage before the GDS.
If the XML object is not present as an XML object, I'll engage the destination vendor to work on a solution.

Our Current Flow
GDS - Does <nameprefix> exist?
Parent Hotel Company - NamePrefix does not exist when it flows downstream.
Site Minder - Is only a passthrough. Nothing is changed
Destination (Opera Cloud) - NamePrefix XML Does not exist when ingested

Comment: For questions related to Enterprise APIs we suggest you to get in touch with your account manager. In this channel we only provide support for Self-Service APIs.

Comment: Hi @anna_ts 

I'm not a customer. I'm an external party bought in to aid the client in resolving the issue due to vendors pointing fingers at each other.

At this stage, all I want to know is if the <namePrefix> is an object passed downstream from the GDS. It's not a complex question. I really don't want to spend weeks jumping through hoops for a simple yes or no answer.